# Suggestions for printing content with Django

Tags: django, reportlab

I'm developing a django project (multiuser/multicustomer), and I'm looking for a "print solution".

My first idea was to generate a PDF and let the user print by himself.

Reading the django documentation I've found the note:

> ReportLab is not thread-safe. Some of our users have reported odd issues with building PDF-generating Django views that are accessed by many people at the same time.

After searching a bit on google, I've also found some users complaining about weird issues with reportlab on multiuser systems.

Any ideas/suggestions for printing?

As a sidenote, the requirement for this application is a modern browser (updated Firefox or Chrome, so old browsers are not an issue).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a PDF. All browsers support a print-specific CSS stylesheet, so you can format your output as you like.

```
<link href="/static/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```